# Postfix: Recipient address rejected: Invalid HELO/EHLO

Tags: postfix, outlook, outlook-2007, email-server

**The problem seems to be the MS Outlook 2007 not sending SMTP AUTH for some strange reason for only one specific domain.**

I run iRedMail server (it's using stock debian 7/wheezy, postfix 2.9.6-2) for my domain and few dozens of client domains.
The problem is I have a client unable to send email to myself (not just my email but the whole domain) - it gets rejected due `reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname` but the client is using SMTP AUTH and has it correctly set, so it should bypass the FQDN check. It just looks like the MUA is not using SMTP AUTH only for my and my coleaques email addresses.

Has anyone seen this before? How can I workaround this problem? Any input is highly appreciated!

Could it be it's connected to MUA? She is using Outlook (not Express)?

Have a look on following snips of logs showing different situations. All was catched in the same configuration/same MUA/IP's, ...:

1) this is OK: My client sends email to third party server; using SMTP AUTH

```
May 28 13:02:13 email2 postfix/smtpd[1191]: connect from <censored>
May 28 13:02:13 email2 postfix/smtpd[1191]: 28A5D35E61DC: client=<censored>, sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=<client1@1.example.com>
May 28 13:02:26 email2 postfix/cleanup[1435]: 28A5D35E61DC: message-id=<006c01ce5b92$d33805e0$79a811a0$@cz>
May 28 13:02:44 email2 postfix/qmgr[376]: 28A5D35E61DC: from=<client1@1.example.com>, size=4392922, nrcpt=7 (queue active)
May 28 13:02:44 email2 postfix/smtp[1580]: 28A5D35E61DC: to=<someone@thirdparty.example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=32, delays=31/0/0/0.88, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B061435E61DE)
May 28 13:02:47 email2 postfix/qmgr[376]: 28A5D35E61DC: removed
```

2) this is OK:
My client sends email to local account (hers coleque); she is using SMTP AUTH

```
May 28 13:06:18 email2 postfix/smtpd[2519]: connect from <censored>
May 28 13:06:18 email2 postfix/smtpd[2519]: 49CE735E61D4: client=<censored>, sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=<client1@1.example.com>
May 28 13:06:18 email2 postfix/cleanup[429]: 49CE735E61D4: message-id=<007201ce5b93$5df069c0$19d13d40$@cz>
May 28 13:06:19 email2 postfix/qmgr[376]: 49CE735E61D4: from=<client1@1.example.com>, size=10875, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 28 13:06:19 email2 postfix/smtp[2295]: 49CE735E61D4: to=<client2@1.example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.6, delays=1.2/0/0/0.43, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as CC61F35E61D7)
May 28 13:06:19 email2 postfix/qmgr[376]: 49CE735E61D4: removed
```

3) problem, email sent to my account (same server, but different domain), NOT using SMTP AUTH???:

```
May 28 13:04:38 email2 postfix/smtpd[1433]: connect from <censored>
May 28 13:04:38 email2 postfix/smtpd[1433]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from <censored>: 554 5.7.1 <my_email>>: Recipient address rejected: Invalid HELO/EHLO; Must be a FQDN or an address literal, not 'xxx'; from=<client1@1.example.com> to=<my_address> proto=ESMTP helo=
May 28 13:04:41 email2 postfix/smtpd[1433]: disconnect from <censored>
```

Part of postfix configuration:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                            reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
                            permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                               reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                               reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                               reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                               reject_unlisted_recipient,
                               check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777,
                               check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
                               permit_mynetworks,
                               permit_sasl_authenticated,
                               reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                          permit_sasl_authenticated,
                          reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
                          reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
                          check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
```

See output of [postconf](http://pastebin.com/FSWHaddB) and [cat main.cfg](http://pastebin.com/QG20y3QM)

Comment: The client is not sending a fqdn hostname in the HELO parameter of the smtp dialog. You have two options: set the HELO correct in the client (which can be difficult). For the second option, it would be helpfull if you could post your postfix config, especially the smtpd_recipient_restrictions (if thats what you use). You should have the option that permits authorized senders bevore the fqdn hostname check.

Comment: I have updated the question with part of postfix config. So I should move `permit_sasl_authenticated` toward beginning of the checks? What place would you suggest?

Comment: I put `permit_sasl_authenticated` first or second, second if I use `permit_my_networks`.

Comment: Btw: I would recommend to put all of the restrictions in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the policyd (cluebringer)... it was not seen from the log for the first look, that reject was not from postfix restriction but from the policyd.

**Background**

I had in cluebringers group internal_domains only my primary domain (after install) and all new domains wasn't there... To solve the problem I decided to empty the internal_domains and everything works as expected now.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

HELO/EHLO happens **before** the SMTP authentication. If your server is configured with `reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname = yes`, it will reject any connection with an invalid hostname **before** getting to the SMTP AUTH part.

While keeping this rejection will cut down on some spam, it will also block a number of legitimate mails. You should take a closer look at tthe Postfix documentation for [reject_invalid_helo_hostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_invalid_helo_hostname) and [smtp_helo_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_helo_restrictions) to figure out how you want this to work.

Comment: My `smtpd_helo_restrictions` are updated in the question. It permits authenticated before the EHLO check?

Answer (score 0):

Your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` are ok under the assumption that all your clients are well behaving. Since they are not (not sending correct HELO), you should at least have something like

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, 
                               reject_unknown_recipient_domain, 
                               permit_sasl_authenticated, 
                               reject_non_fqdn_sender, 
                               reject_non_fqdn_recipient, 
                               reject_unlisted_recipient, 
                               check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, 
                               check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, 
                               permit_mynetworks, 
                               reject_unauth_destination
```

Even better:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access-recipient-rfc,
    check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/access-client,
    check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/access-helo,
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access-sender,
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access-recipient,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,
    # greylisting
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023,
    # policyd-weight
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:12525,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_unverified_recipient,
    permit
```

Furthermore you should integrate all restrictions in the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. Since [HELO comes bevore the SASL authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication), its no use to permit SASL authentication in the `smtpd_helo_restrictions`.

In general its good practise to use just `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, since you can do everything there, it saves you repeating stuff, and the network overhead of connections that would have been terminated after helo is not substantial.

Comment: I'm testing the first version as the quick fix now and will try to migrate to the second version in case everything will go fine. I really appreciate you input!

Comment: What is very strange / the problem is here only for my domain, not any other domain hosted on the same server. I greped thru the logs of the whole day and emails are rejected only for my domain. Do you have any idea why? I also don't understand which check did the reject? Pls. help me to understand it...

Comment: Maybe you can post all of your main.cf. Did you try the same client with other domains?

Comment: I put on the bottom of my question output of `postconf` and copy of `main.cf`

Comment: Before I start to implement your solution - do you have any idea why is the restriction in effect only for my domain? In the question I show 3 sent emails, two are OK and the one to myself is not. All attempts are made from the same computer with the same (bad) EHLO name...

Comment: Good question ... is your domain any different than the others? I see you have `relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf`. Is your domain listet in the same database as the others? Or is it just in `mydestination`?

Comment: I'm not aware of any special settings - mydomain is not in relay_domains and neither in mydestination. Just amavis has some special setup (DKIM, local_domains_maps) and `search mydomain` in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Hm, I am sorry, at this point I have no further idea.